# Published dynamic component template not found under published items

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

I am new to Dynamic Component Templates.

I have created a Component Template and made it "Published as Dynamic Component" and allowed "Allow on Page using Dynamic Assembly".

I don’t have Deployer configured in my system and all published items are getting stored at some local location.

I have published this Component Template and I am trying to find the published CT.
I did not find this CT in published items.

Is Deployer compulsory to work with Dynamic CT and how to create pages using dynamic  CT.

Can any provide some solution to this?

**EDIT**

Addinf storageconfig file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration Version="6.1"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schemas/cd_storage_conf.xsd">
    <Global>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <ObjectCache Enabled="false">
            <!--Optional:-->
            <Policy Type="LRU" Class="com.tridion.cache.LRUPolicy">

                <Param Name="MemSize" Value="16mb"/>
            </Policy>


            <Features>
                <Feature Type="DependencyTracker" Class="com.tridion.cache.DependencyTracker"/>
            </Features>

        </ObjectCache>

        <Storages>

            <Storage Type="persistence" Id="defaultdb" dialect="MSSQL" Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory" defaultStorage="true">
                <Pool Type="jdbc" Size="5" MonitorInterval="60" IdleTimeout="120" CheckoutTimeout="120" />
                <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
                    <Property Name="serverName" Value="MyserverName" />
                    <Property Name="portNumber" Value="MYPORT" />
                    <Property Name="databaseName" Value="Tridion_Broker" />
                    <Property Name="user" Value="TridionBrokerUser" />
                    <Property Name="password" Value="MyPassword" />
                </DataSource>
            </Storage>



            <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="defaultFile" defaultFilesystem="false">
                <Root Path="c:\temp" />
            </Storage>
            <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="defaultDataFile" defaultFilesystem="true" defaultStorage="false">
                <Root Path="c:\temp\data" />
            </Storage>


        </Storages>

    </Global>

    <ItemTypes defaultStorageId="defaultdb" cached="false">

        <Item typeMapping="Page" cached="false" storageId="defaultFile"/>


            <Item typeMapping="ComponentPresentation" itemExtension=".Jsp" storageId="defaultFile"/>
            <Item typeMapping="ComponentPresentation" itemExtension=".Asp" storageId="defaultFile"/>
            <Item typeMapping="ComponentPresentation" itemExtension=".Xml" storageId="defaultFile"/>
            <Item typeMapping="ComponentPresentation" itemExtension=".Txt" storageId="defaultFile"/>

    </ItemTypes>


</Configuration>
```

To be clear again I have published component Template which is Dynamic, though the CT is published I am unable to find in published Items in server. The published items are being stored at **c:\temp**

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Let's start at the beginning. Did you link that dynamic CT to a schema? Do you have a component based on that schema? Is that component marked as 'published' in the GUI? That is to say: does it have a little globe on the icon?

Comment: @Quirjin. I have linked that dynamic CT to schema.I have linked schema to CT. I have published CT and component. Both are published and Globe is there on the top of the icons.

Comment: Even after specifying its location. I am not able to find CT under published items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check your storage config file (cd_storage_conf.xml) for Dynamic CPs location. If you have not specified it will use the default location.

You may specify your own location

```
<ItemTypes defaultStorageId="Default Storage" cached="CACHE_BEHAVIOR">

    <Item typeMapping="ComponentPresentation" itemExtension=".Jsp" cached="CACHE_BEHAVIOR" storageId="DCPStorage" />
......
</ItemTypes>
```

Comment: Thanks you for helping me.In cd_storage_config.xml, I have seen statement  <Item typeMapping="DynamicLinkInfo" cached="true" storageId="defaultFile"/>. But it is there twice and commented. Are you referring to this only?

Comment: Check location from (<ItemTypes defaultStorageId="STORAGE_ID">) here.. if not specified.

Comment: @User222 -- As Vikas mentioned, you should be concern about <Item typeMapping="ComponentPresentation" rather than <Item typeMapping="DynamicLinkInfo"

Comment: @vikaskumar,@Ram S . I have this in xml.<Item typeMapping="ComponentPresentation" itemExtension=".Jsp" storageId="defaultFile"/>
   <Item typeMapping="ComponentPresentation" itemExtension=".Asp" storageId="defaultFile"/>
   <Item typeMapping="ComponentPresentation" itemExtension=".Xml" storageId="defaultFile"/>
   <Item typeMapping="ComponentPresentation" itemExtension=".Txt" storageId="defaultFile"/>.But Its commented.

Comment: @User222 Did you verify from CMS if DCP has published?

Comment: @vikaskumar. I have published the component Template and its successfully published(Globe on the ICON). Component is alos published succussfully.But they are not getting added at local storage.

Comment: @User222 Can you edit your question with with full <ItemTypes> tag and <Storage> tag

Comment: @user222 Check path in this node <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="defaultFile"> <Root Path="c:\temp\data" </Storage> Is something available over there.

Comment: @RamS. I have checked the location c:\temp\data. I did not find any thing.